# What is the difference between find() and find_all() in beautiful soup python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was doing web scraping but i stuck/confused in find() and find_all().

Like where to use find_all, where to user find().

Also, where can i use this methods like in **for loop** or in **ul li** list ??

**Here is the code i tried**

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls = "https://www.flipkart.com/offers-list/latest-launches?screen=dynamic&pk=themeViews%3DAug19-Latest-launch-Phones%3ADTDealcard~widgetType%3DdealCard~contentType%3Dneo&wid=7.dealCard.OMU_5&otracker=hp_omu_Latest%2BLaunches_5&otracker1=hp_omu_WHITELISTED_neo%2Fmerchandising_Latest%2BLaunches_NA_wc_view-all_5"

source = requests.get(urls)

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='MDGhAp')

names = divs.find_all('a')

full_name = names.find_all('div', class_='iUmrbN').text

print(full_name)
```

And got error like this

```
  File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/utube/sunil.py", line 9, in <module>
    names = divs.find_all('a')
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1601, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

So can anyone explain where should i use **find** and **find all** ??

Answer (score 3):

find()-  It just returns the result when the searched element is found in the page.And the return type will be `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`.

find_all()- It returns all the matches (i.e) it scans the entire document and returns all the results and the return type will be `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>`

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser = RoboBrowser(parser='html.parser')
browser.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
res=browser.find('h3')
print(type(res),res)
print(" ")
res=browser.find_all('h3')
print(type(res),res)
print(" ")
print("Iterating the Resultset")
print(" ")
for x in range(0,len(res)):
  print(x,res[x])
  print(" ")
```

Output:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> <h3><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">current community</a>
</h3>

<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'> [<h3><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">current community</a>
</h3>, <h3>
your communities            </h3>, <h3><a href="https://stackexchange.com/sites">more stack exchange communities</a>
</h3>, <h3 class="w90 mx-auto ta-center p-ff-roboto-slab-bold fs-headline2 mb24">Questions are everywhere, answers are on Stack Overflow</h3>, <h3 class="w90 mx-auto ta-center p-ff-roboto-slab-bold fs-headline2 mb24">Learn and grow with Stack Overflow</h3>, <h3 class="mx-auto w90 wmx12 p-ff-roboto-slab-bold fs-headline2 mb24 lg:ta-center">Looking for a job?</h3>]

Iterating the Resultset

0 <h3><a href="https://stackoverflow.com">current community</a>
</h3>

1 <h3>
your communities            </h3>

2 <h3><a href="https://stackexchange.com/sites">more stack exchange communities</a>
</h3>

3 <h3 class="w90 mx-auto ta-center p-ff-roboto-slab-bold fs-headline2 mb24">Questions are everywhere, answers are on Stack Overflow</h3>

4 <h3 class="w90 mx-auto ta-center p-ff-roboto-slab-bold fs-headline2 mb24">Learn and grow with Stack Overflow</h3>

5 <h3 class="mx-auto w90 wmx12 p-ff-roboto-slab-bold fs-headline2 mb24 lg:ta-center">Looking for a job?</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this example maybe is more clear :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
</ul>
"""   
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for n in soup.find('li'):
  # It Give you one element     
  print(n)

for n in soup.find_all('li'):    
  # It Give you all elements
  print(n)
```

Result :

```
First

<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
```

For more information pls read this https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all

Answer (score 0):

Found this from the Beautiful Soup documentation. If you are scraping something more specific, try `find` and if you are scraping something more general from `a` or `span`, probably give find_all a try. 
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

```
soup.find_all('a')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]

soup.find(id="link3")
# <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let us understand with the help of an example: I am trying to get the list of book names on the mentioned website. (https://www.bookdepository.com/bestsellers)

To iterate through all the book related tags at once I use **find_all** command, subsequently I use **find** inside each list item to get the title of the book.

**Note**: **find** will fetch you the first match (only match in this case) while **find_all** will produce a list of all matching items, which you can use futher to iterate through.)

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs`

`import requests`

`url = "https://www.bookdepository.com/bestsellers"`

`response = requests.get(url)`

Use **find_all** to go through all book items:

[image]

`a=soup.find_all("div",class_ = "item-info")`

Use **find** to go through title of each book inside each book item

[image]

`for i in a:`

```
print(i.find("h3",class_ = "title").get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

[From Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find)

The find_all() method scans the entire document looking for results, but sometimes you only want to find one result. If you know a document only has one  tag, it’s a waste of time to scan the entire document looking for more. Rather than passing in limit=1 every time you call find_all, you can use the find() method ... both next sentences are equivalent :

```
soup.find_all('title', limit=1)

soup.find('title')
```